# National Insurance Number

Tags: united-kingdom, health-insurance, social-security

I worked in the UK from 1976 - 1989 and am currently living in Italy. I would like to return to work and live in the UK. Is my previous NI number still valid?

Answer (score 3):

I could find several sources confirming that the National insurance number does not expire, so your NI number is still valid.

Sources:

- [migrationobservatory.ox.ac.uk](http://www.migrationobservatory.ox.ac.uk/data-and-resources/data-sources-and-limitations/national-insurance-numbers)
- [britishexpats.com](http://britishexpats.com/forum/moving-back-uk-61/using-national-insurance-number-after-25-years-abroad-487638/)